# Why Our Jobs are not showing in Google For Jobs

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-jobs

Would you please let us know the reason why our jobs are not found in Google For Jobs? This issue started from 8-Jun 2022 and still not found our jobs in Google For Jobs.

Can somebody help us to solve the problem?

**Problem**- Why Jobs are not showing in Google For Jobs

We already checked below:

1. Job Posting schema added
2. On Page & Schema Content are same
3. Sitemap - We already have separate sitemap for jobs
4. We are also using Google indexing APIs.
5. No Malware on Page
6. We are following all job posting guidelines as well as schema guidelines

Please let us know. Thanks

Comment: What does your [rich result status report](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/job-posting#after-deploying) in Google Search Console say?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.